# WebGL texture tiling edge artifacts with mipmap

Tags: textures, webgl, tiling, mipmaps

I am tiling a surface in WebGL using a texture that requires mipmap to look good (non-negotiable). Because WebGL does not support a wrapping mode of gl.REPEAT for mipmap'ed textures, I clamp texture coordinates myself using 'fract(texcoord)' in the fragment shader.

As a consequence, I get artifacts at the edge of the texture, since the 'fract(texcoord)' wraps around and hence makes the GPU think that it only needs a low detail mipmap.

If this had been ordinary OpenGL, I could use textureGrad to tell the GPU about the real gradient, but unfortunately this is not available in WebGL.

Any suggestions? I am aware of the 4-tap trick described at 
http://0fps.net/2013/07/09/texture-atlases-wrapping-and-mip-mapping/ but that seems like a lot of extra overhead and only makes the effect less severe, not go away entirely. I have also seen the suggestion in [Threejs Custom Shader - Screen Tearing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13271205/threejs-custom-shader-screen-tearing) to use the 'lod' parameter of texture, but that does not quite solve the problem (moreover, the answer is from 2012 so there may be better solutions now?).

Comment: WebGL supports repeating for mipmapped textures just fine. It's only limit is the textures must be a power of 2 in each dimension. Texture that are not a power of 2 can't be mipmapped or repeated period. Proof a repeated mipmap support is [here](http://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/webgl-3d-textures-mips-tri-linear.html).  Did I misunderstand your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WebGL does just fine with repeat. Your texture needs to be a power of two size in each direction - not necessarily the same. 
The same requirement holds for being able to use mip maps (at all!) also.
It is a bit hidden in the spec.

Comment: Aargh, originally got stuck on the POT issue, then misread the specs to say that I couldn't have repeat with mipmap at all... You're right, it does work...